# Remove empty values from chart parameters

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to remove the empty values in the picture below from appearing in the chart?

The code is at this link: https://www.tradingview.com/v/UGSk1G42/

[image: Illustration of what I want to be gone]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are not empty values.

They are crossover calculations, so when there is no crossover in play it equals zero 0. When a crossover is in play it is equal to 1.

If you put the put your mouse over the signals (green and red triangles) you will see that one of the zeros 0 turn to 1.

There are six zeros in your picture, below are the lines of code that are either true=1 or false=0.

If you were to remove the below code you would remove the "ones and zeros", but you would then also lose the visual triangle signals.

```
// monthly trend
plotshape(series=crossover(sma_month, sma_quarter), title="SMA Uptrend", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, text="SMA Monthly", size=size.small)
plotshape(series=crossunder(sma_month, sma_quarter), title="SMA Downtrend", style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, text="SMA Monthly", size=size.small)

// quarterly trend
plotshape(series=crossover(sma_quarter, sma_halfYear), title="SMA Uptrend", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, text="SMA Quarterly", size=size.small)
plotshape(series=crossunder(sma_quarter, sma_halfYear), title="SMA Downtrend", style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, text="SMA Quaterly", size=size.small)

// yearly trend
plotshape(series=crossover(sma_halfYear, sma_year), title="SMA Uptrend", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, text="SMA Yearly", size=size.small)
plotshape(series=crossunder(sma_halfYear, sma_year), title="SMA Downtrend", style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, text="SMA Yearly", size=size.small)
```

Comment: You're right friend "frien_dd"! Thank you very much, I didn't notice that <3

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to exclude plotshape return value from appearing on the chart?

Answer (score 2):

You may be satisfied with the ability to configure the workspace. But this setting will be applied for all indicators.

[image]

Comment: oh I see, thank you very much @AnyDozer! Do you know if there's a way to omit indicator values by script? e.g. stop return values from the `plotshape()` function to be displayed on the chart.

Comment: No that's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

That's currently not possible yet in Pine Script.

Comment: do you know what are they? are they caused by the variables declaration? what creates them exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You could use alertconditions but that means you would have to setup 6 Alerts and depending on what TradingView Membership you might not be able to do it.

This would get rid of the values but also the display visual and will send you a pop up alert when the condition is met.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Monthly, Quaterly, Yearly SMA Trends", shorttitle="SMATrends", overlay=true, linktoseries=true)

// you can update the SMA values here (rounded values)
sma_month = sma(close, 20) // 20 trading days in a month
sma_quarter = sma(close, 60) // 60 trading days in a quarter
sma_halfYear = sma(close, 120) // 120 trading days in half a year
sma_year = sma(close, 250) // 250 trading days in a year

// you can comment to disable trendlines in the chart
plot(sma_month, title="20 SMA", color=#003C7B, linewidth=2, transp=50)
plot(sma_quarter, title="60 SMA", color=#FC8A10, linewidth=1, transp=50)
plot(sma_halfYear, title="120 SMA", color=#00DB00, linewidth=1, transp=50)
plot(sma_year, title="250 SMA", color=#FEDA15, linewidth=1, transp=50)



alertcondition(crossover(sma_month, sma_quarter), title="SMA Monthly Uptrend", message="SMA Monthly Uptrend")
alertcondition(crossunder(sma_month, sma_quarter), title="SMA Monthly Downtrend", message="SMA Monthly Downtrend")

alertcondition(crossover(sma_quarter, sma_halfYear), title="SMA Quaterly Uptrend", message="SMA Quaterly Uptrend")
alertcondition(crossunder(sma_quarter, sma_halfYear), title="SMA Quaterly Downtrend", message="SMA Quaterly Downtrend")

alertcondition(crossover(sma_halfYear, sma_year), title="SMA Yearly Uptrend", message="SMA Yearly Uptrend")
alertcondition(crossunder(sma_halfYear, sma_year), title="SMA Yearly Downtrend", message="SMA Yearly Downtrend")
```

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about this question a little further I think the below meets your original request.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Monthly, Quaterly, Yearly SMA Trends", shorttitle="SMATrends", overlay=true, linktoseries=true)

// you can update the SMA values here (rounded values)
sma_month = sma(close, 20) // 20 trading days in a month
sma_quarter = sma(close, 60) // 60 trading days in a quarter
sma_halfYear = sma(close, 120) // 120 trading days in half a year
sma_year = sma(close, 250) // 250 trading days in a year

// you can comment to disable trendlines in the chart
plot(sma_month, title="20 SMA", color=#003C7B, linewidth=2, transp=50)
plot(sma_quarter, title="60 SMA", color=#FC8A10, linewidth=1, transp=50)
plot(sma_halfYear, title="120 SMA", color=#00DB00, linewidth=1, transp=50)
plot(sma_year, title="250 SMA", color=#FEDA15, linewidth=1, transp=50)

// monthly trend

SMAMUp = crossover(sma_month, sma_quarter)
if SMAMUp
    label.new(bar_index, na, text="SMA Monthly Uptrend", yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.green, style=label.style_label_up) 

SMAMDown = crossunder(sma_month, sma_quarter)
if SMAMDown
    label.new(bar_index, na, text="SMA Monthly Downtrend", yloc=yloc.abovebar, color=color.red, style=label.style_label_down) 


SMAQUp = crossover(sma_quarter, sma_halfYear)
if SMAQUp
    label.new(bar_index, na, text="SMA Quarterly Uptrend", yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.green, style=label.style_label_up) 
SMAQDown = crossunder(sma_quarter, sma_halfYear)
if SMAQDown
    label.new(bar_index, na, text="SMA Quarterly Downtrend", yloc=yloc.abovebar, color=color.red, style=label.style_label_down) 

SMAYUp = crossover(sma_halfYear, sma_year)
if SMAYUp
    label.new(bar_index, na, text="SMA Yearly Uptrend", yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.green, style=label.style_label_up) 
SMAYDown = crossunder(sma_halfYear, sma_year)
if SMAYDown
    label.new(bar_index, na, text="SMA Yearly Downtrend", yloc=yloc.abovebar, color=color.red, style=label.style_label_down)
```

Comment: I see you're forced to use a Label b/c of pinescript context limitations